# WOO order detail admin section

Tags: woocommerce

When I am managing order details, it shows total price incl tax at the bottom, but I need to show prices incl tax on each product line. Woo Standard shows products with price without tax and the tax at each product line and then at the bottom the final price with VAT.

I found a solution to show an additional column to show the product price with VAT. This works fine.

```
function action_woocommerce_admin_order_item_values( $null, $item, $absint ) {
    $val = ($item['type'] == 'line_item' || $item['type'] == 'shipping') ? $item['total'] + $item['total_tax'] : '&nbsp;';
    $valdecimal = wc_format_decimal( $val, $dp='', $trim_zeros );
    ?>
    <td class="item_fcost" data-sort-value="<?php echo $val; ?>">
        <div class="view" style="font-weight: bold; text-align: right; padding-right: 10px;">
            <?php if ($val>0) echo '€'; echo $valdecimal;?>
        </div>
    </td>
    <?php
};
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_item_values', 'action_woocommerce_admin_order_item_values', 10, 3 );

function action_woocommerce_admin_order_item_headers( $order ) {
    echo '<th class="item_fcost sortable" data-sort="float" style="text-align: right;">Preço com IVA</th>';
};
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_item_headers', 'action_woocommerce_admin_order_item_headers', 10, 3 );
```

Here a view of the page image "as is"

[image: As is]

I need a resorting of the columns like image "result"

[image: result]

How can I do this?

Thank you for an answer.

Best regards
Siegfried